# Looking for genkey() method in Perl

Tags: perl

I am going through the Camel book and there is an example under the `map` function that includes a method `genkey()`. I have been unable to find a module that provides that method except `OpenCA::OpenSSL`, and that module has `genKey()`. I would try that but unfortunately I am unable to successfully build that module. So, is there a module that would provide me with `genkey()` that can be used for the `map` example? For reference, the example is on page 895 of the 4th edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples are just examples. They are not useful code or designed toward any purpose. Here are those examples, both of which do the same unspecified thing. Very similar examples show up in [the official documentation for map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

```
%hash = map { genkey($_) => $_ } @array;


%hash = ();
for my $_ (@array) {
    $hash{genkey($_)} = $_; 
}
```

The `genkey` is not special. It's a stand-in for something useful that you supply. For example, let's suppose you wanted the key to be all uppercase, you can use the `uc` builtin:

```
%hash = map { uc($_) => $_ } @array;
```

The `map` simply provides a list to assign to `%hash`. The fictional `genkey` does not set any attributes or magic to make some of the list elements suitable to be keys. It's just does whatever is appropriate for your task to create a string to index your values.